# Powershell adding multithreading to finished script

Tags: multithreading, powershell, start-job

I got a scirpt, that is working fine, but I want to speed up it a little, by using multithreading. The problem is, that it's kinda difficult to do it, without changing a lot of code. I would love to avoid jobs with new separated scopes, but it looks like it's impossible. Also starting-job is really slow, it needs ~~150miliseconds to start execution. Is there any way to avoid jobs, or atleast make this script block work, as expected? (no doubled functions, passing arguments correctly)

```
Param(
    [int]$arg1 = 2, [int]$arg2 = 3
)
$functionDoSomething = { 
    function doSomething($inp) { 
        return $inp + 10
    }
}

function doSomething($inp) { 
    return $inp + 10
}

# time: 1523337 ticks
Measure-Command {
    Start-Job -Name Job1 -InitializationScript $functionDoSomething -ScriptBlock {
        return doSomething ($arg1 + $arg2)
    } -ArgumentList $arg1, $arg2
    Wait-Job Job1
    $var2 = Receive-Job Job1 # result is 10, so arguements aren't passed correctly, trick with @($arg1, arg2) = the same result
}

# time: 6867 ticks
Measure-Command {
    $var3 = doSomething ($arg1 + $arg2) # result is 15
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Have no fear - Invoke-Parallel is here. Hoping that I can help steer you in the right direction. Let me show you some pseudo code that can point you in the right direction.

# You need a list of objects in which you want to perform an operation for
$listOfComputers = @(
'1'
'2'
'3'
)

# Pipe your array to Invoke-Parallel which takes care of opening threads depending on the amount of objects piped in. 
# If you want to control the amount of simultaneous threads simply help Invoke-Parallel -ShowWindow to see how
$results = $listOfComputers | Invoke-Parallel -ScriptBlock {
function doSomething($inp) 
{ 
    return [int]$inp + 10
}
if ($_ -eq '1') { Start-Sleep -Seconds 15; Write-Verbose 'Waited 15s' } # Adding this so you can see that this script block is running in a multi-threaded fashion
# $_ refers to the values inside of $listOfComputers
return doSomething ($_)
} -Verbose

$results

<# Notice how 11 comes up last 
12
13
11
#>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But there is one problem with this solution, my script is working in enterprise environment, where adding extern modules (not from PS) is kinda problematic. Also, script is intended to work on one machine, and speed up things by calling part of script in new threads. I'm not sure, if this solution would work like that.

Comment: Well this isn't an external module. It's simply a function that facilitates the work for you. Why re-invent the wheel right? Simply download the Invoke-Parallel.ps1 file. At the beginning of your own script simply load this function so that it's available for consumption by using Import-Module 'Invoke-Parallel.ps1'. This function uses .NET System.Management.Automation.Runspaces which bypasses Start-Job and all of it's overhead.

Comment: I will give it a try then :)

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I finally get it, how it works. But I got one more question. Is there any better way to import functions to both scopes, than saving function code to file and then importing it in both scopes?

Comment: What do you mean by "both scopes"? I am going to assume that you mean script scope and then the individual runspaces have their own scope. Invoke-Parallel does not support importing the available script scoped functions so you have to import them inside of the -ScriptBlock as shown in the example provided. You can also call Import-Module 'MyFunction.ps1' from inside Invoke-Parallel to get rid of some of the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

First, look into Runspaces and a RunSpacePool.  When you create a runspace you can specify which modules get loaded other than the default.  See here http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189 for more details.

```
$ScriptBlock = {
 param([string]$forinput)
  "Do something with $forinput"

   [PSCusomObject]@{
    Line1="Something"
    Line2="Something done to $forinput"
    }#end of custom object output

}#end script block

#Create Runspace pool, 100 min and max.
#Example data contained within $item.property
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(100,100)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Jobs = 
 foreach ( $item in $VariableContainsListOfInput)
 {
  $Job = [powershell]::Create().
  AddScript($ScriptBlock).
  AddArgument($item.property)
  $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

 [PSCustomObject]@{
  Pipe = $Job
  Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()
 }
}

DO{Start-sleep -seconds 1
}While($Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)

#Loop through jobs, pipe EndInvoke data from runspace into Export-CSV
$(ForEach ($Job in $Jobs)
{ $Job.Pipe.EndInvoke($Job.Result) }) |
 Export-Csv -Path "$FullPath\$file" -NoTypeInformation
#clean up runspace
$RunspacePool.Close()
$RunspacePool.Dispose()
```

Comment: It's really nice solution, thank you. But I think that using Invoke-Parallel from Alberto's answer is a lot simpler, with similar results (ofcourse it's slower). I will give it a try, maybe it only looks complicated :p

Comment: You are welcome!  It looked complicated to me also, the important part is the script block and the `PSCustomObject` which is the output that is sent to `Export-CSV`  The bonus here is you can create that object which can be piped into another function/script.  The power in PowerShell is Objects :)