# Function not accessible in a ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, powershell-5.0

I have a script that has some functions and then multiple jobs in the very same script that use those functions. When I start a new job they don't seem to be accessible in the `[ScriptBlock]` that I have for my jobs.

Here's a minimal example demonstrating this:

```
# A simple test function
function Test([string] $string)
{
    Write-Output "I'm a $string"
}

# My test job
[ScriptBlock] $test =
{
    Test "test function"
}

# Start the test job
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $test -Name "Test" | Out-Null

# Wait for jobs to complete and print their output
@(Get-Job).ForEach({
    Wait-Job -Job $_ |Out-Null
    Receive-Job -Job $_ | Write-Host
})

# Remove the completed jobs
Remove-Job -State Completed
```

The error that I get in PowerShell ISE is:

```
The term 'Test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Comment: `Start-Job` create separate clean (it does not import your profile or share session state with calling PowerShell session) PowerShell process for each job. So, yes, nothing from your current PowerShell session (like aliases, function, variables, etc.) are accessible from job.

Comment: Include the function inside the job-scriptblock.

Comment: @FrodeF. That is not possible, as the function is used by multiple jobs.

Comment: I didn't suggest you take it away from the others, just that you specifically load/define it inside the scriptblock too.

Comment: @PetSerAl That is unfortunate to hear. I guess I'm going to need to split the functions used by multiple jobs into a module, as defining them in every `ScriptBlock` doesn't seem like a good solution. Could you also turn your comment into an answer with possible suggestions for solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Start-Job` run jobs in separate PowerShell processes. So that, jobs do not have access to session state of calling PowerShell session. You need to define functions, which get used by jobs, in every job. An easy way to do that without duplicating the code would be using of `-InitializationScript` parameter, where all common functions can be defined.

```
$IS = {
    function CommonFunction1 {
        'Do something'
    }
    function CommonFunction2 {
        'Do something else'
    }
}
$SB1 = {
    CommonFunction1
    CommonFunction2
}
$SB2 = {
    CommonFunction2
    CommonFunction1
}
$Job1 = Start-Job -InitializationScript $IS -ScriptBlock $SB1
$Job2 = Start-Job -InitializationScript $IS -ScriptBlock $SB2
Receive-Job $Job1,$Job2 -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extending PetSerAl's answer, you can use Runspaces for this, if you want faster code and a little bit more organised. Check out this question:
[39180266](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180266/powershell-adding-multithreading-to-finished-script)

So when you run something in different runspace, you need to import functions in both of them. So finished structure would look like:

1. `Module: functions.ps1` - you store here functions to share with both scopes.
2. `Main script: script.ps1` - it's basically your script, with runspaces, but without functions from functions.ps1.

And in beginning of your script.ps1, just simply call `Import-module .\functions.ps1`, to get access to your functions. Remember that runscape has different scope, and in their scriptblock, you have to call import-module once again. Full example:

```
#file functions.ps1
function add($inp) {
     return $inp + 2
}


#file script.ps1
Import-module .\functions.ps1        #or you can use "dot call": . .\function.ps1
Import-module .\invoke-parallel.ps1  #it's extern module
$argument = 10                       #it may be any object, even your custom class

$results = $argument | Invoke-Parallel -ScriptBlock {
    import-module .\functions.ps1    #you may have to use here absolute path, because in a new runspace PSScriptRoot may be different/undefined
    return (add $_)                  # $_ is simply passed object from "parent" scope, in fact, the relationship between scopes is not child-parent
}

echo $result # it's 12
echo (add 5) # it's 7
```

Comment: You can also use a module that I wrote called PoshRSJob (https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) which allows you to import functions using the -FunctionsToImport parameter. `1..10|Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock {Do-Something;Function1} -FunctionsToImport Function1,Function2`